# Is it possible to install Magento 2 in Wamp Server in 2024?

Tags: magento2.4, wamp, zip, magento-install

**I´ve tried so many ways and I cant do it someone please help me, this is literally my school final project. I think its because the Magento zip isn´t available on the original site anymore, I dont know if its still possible to do, someone help me please. I've tried with composer but it says it doesnt find the file.**

Comment: so please share with me which composer commands are installed for Magento. after that, I will help you.

Comment: which type of Magento version installed so please tell me.

Comment: To install Magento on a Windows environment, you can follow the steps provided in the URL.
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-on-localhost/ Magento has a preference for Linux environments due to a limitation on Windows. Thanks

Comment: hello dear issue your wamp server related composer wise php version selecetd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello dear so please refer below link for the Magento version installed on Windows.

https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento2-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/

and more thing when you used wamp sever don't forget below changes.

go to below directory

/wamp/bin/apache/apache(version)/conf/httpd.conf

find below

```
 #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

 to 

 LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

after restarting your Wamp server. so please any issue then tell me.

Comment: So I did all of this steps but when I did the setup:install command to install magento2 it gives me this error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.58\htdocs\magento2\generated\metadata\global.php on line 8  What should I do to fix this? please help me as fast as possible, Im using WampServer3.3.2 Apache2.4.58 PHP8.2.13 MySQL5.7.44 MariaDB10.2.44

Comment: hello xerobin, you can use the below commands in your root directory.

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:up && php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento c:f && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ app/etc

Comment: if you want to learn magento 2 and any issues? please ping me my email id. i will help you.
mohitvamja1991@gmail.com

Comment: can you share your root directory path?

Comment: go to C:\wamp64\bin\php\php_8.2.13\ open php.ini file and find memory_limit  change 128M to 4G and also change below two, 

max_execution_time=18000
max_input_time=1800
memory_limit=4G

after restart the apache server. i think that is working.

Comment: I cant run the command php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento c:f it says that there are no commands defined in the "c" namespace

Comment: php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento s:up && php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile &&
php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento c:f

try this

Comment: when you apply commands which type error shows give me a screenshot.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/YzReeIDmr9cZ It gives me this error when I put php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento c:f

Comment: please remove the generated directory and also remove the var folder in cache page_cache folder not remove .htaccess file.

after that apply the setup upgrade command then di: compile then deploy the content

php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento s:up && php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento s:static-content:de -f

Comment: after that any issue then tell me

Comment: if you use Windows system please refer to the link.

https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento2-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/

Comment: hello dear, have you solved the issue or not?

Comment: i removed the generated directory and /var/cache and /var/page_cache and then did the upgrade, compile and deployed the content and tried the setup:install command and still didn't work it gives me the exact same error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Comment: please increase memory limit wamp sever.

Comment: can we connect ist time after 10 pm

Comment: I already increased memory limit in wamp server, yes we can connect if you want, you want to connect through discord or where?

Comment: Google Meet or skype is possible.?

Comment: I cant do call now cause im in the work and I cant speak loudly, but we can talk for message. It can be via google teams?

Comment: my discord ID is "mohit_gento"